# An unbeatable Tic-Tac-Toe game using exhaustive enumeration of all cases

Tags: c++, beginner, tic-tac-toe, ai

I am a beginner programmer and I've been trying to complete an unbeatable tic-tac-toe program, my code is below. The program itself works, but it seems rather inefficient, as I literally have to type out every case of possible victory or defeat. Any suggestions on how to make the code more efficient, or general suggestions, are appreciated! Everything is in one 500 line program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const short SIZE = 3;

class Board
{
    private:
        char square[SIZE][SIZE], aiMark, userMark;
    public:
        Board();
        void instructions();
        void showBoard();
        //Gets user pre-approved user move.  
        void userMove(short n, short n2)
        {square[n][n2] = userMark;}
        bool checker(short n, short n2);
        void computerMove(short n);
        bool win();
        bool lose();
        bool full();
        void clear();
};

//The constructor initializes each space (square) to a blank space and the markers to x and o.
Board::Board()
{
    userMark = 'x', aiMark = 'o';
    for(short i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(short j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            square[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

//Outlines the basic instructions and coordinate system.
void Board::instructions(){
    cout<<"This is a Tic Tac Toe progam. All of the standard rules of Tic Tac Toe apply (i.e. three in a row is a victory).\n"
        <<"A player may make a move by inputting the coordinance of the point they would like "
        <<"to mark (ex. type \"0 0\" for the first space).\nAn outline of the table "
        <<"and coordinacnes are below:\n"
        <<"\n0 0 | 0 1 | 0 2\n"
        <<"----|-----|----\n"
        <<"1 0 | 1 1 | 1 2\n"
        <<"----|-----|----\n"
        <<"2 0 | 2 1 | 2 2\n\n";

    cout<<"Player 1 will make the first move, followed by Player 2, until the game ends. "
        <<"You are the x's, while the computer is the o's.\n";

    cout<<"Press enter when you are ready to continue. ";
    cin.get();
}

//Shows the current state of the board.
void Board::showBoard()
{
    cout<<square[0][0]<<"  | "<<square[0][1]<<" | "<<square[0][2]<<endl
        <<"---|---|---"<<endl
        <<square[1][0]<<"  | "<<square[1][1]<<" | "<<square[1][2]<<endl
        <<"---|---|---"<<endl
        <<square[2][0]<<"  | "<<square[2][1]<<" | "<<square[2][2]<<endl;
}

//Checks to see if either the computer or user is making a move that has already been made.
bool Board::checker(short n, short n2)
{
    if(square[n][n2] == aiMark || square[n][n2] == userMark){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//A random assignment is made, then based on game type (i.e. if user is Player 1) a
//specialized move is selected, then if any cases of imminent defeat or victory are detected
//it responds accordingly.
void Board::computerMove(short n)
{
    if(win()){
        cout<<"You have won!\n";
        return;
    }

    if(full()){
        cout<<"You have tied the computer!\n";
        return;
    }

    short r, r2, r3;

    double seed;
    seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    r = 0 + rand() % 3;
    r2 = 0 + rand() % 3;

    //Starts off with a random move assignment in the event that no cases fit.
    while(!checker(r, r2)){
        r = 0 + rand() % 3;
        r2 = 0 + rand() % 3;
    }

    switch(n){
        //This code is employs strategies reserved specifically for when the computer moves second.
        case 1:
            if(checker(1,1) && (square[0][0] == userMark || square[0][2] == userMark || square[2][0] == userMark || square[2][2] == userMark)){
                //If the user begins in a corner AI moves to the center.
                r = 1, r2 = 1;
            } else if (square[1][1] == aiMark){
                //After AI moves to the center AI attempts to occupy an edge.
                if(checker(0,1)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 1;
                } else if (checker(1,0)){
                    r = 1, r2 = 0;
                } else if (checker(1,2)){
                    r = 1, r2 = 2;
                } else if (checker(2,1)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 1;
                }
            } else if (square[1][1] == userMark){
                //If the user begins in the center the AI moves to a corner.
                if(checker(0,0)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 0;
                } else if (checker(0,2)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 2;
                } else if (checker(2,0)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 0;
                } else if (checker(2,2)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 2;
                }
            } else if (square[0][1] == userMark || square[1][0] == userMark || square[1][2] == userMark || square[2][1] == userMark){
                //If the user starts on the side the AI moves to the center.
                r=1, r2=1;
            }
            break;

        //This code is employs strategies reserved specifically for when the computer moves first.
        case 2:
            if (checker(0,0) && checker(0,2) && checker(2,0) && checker(2,2)){
                //Makes sure that the computer starts in a corner.
                r3 = 0 + rand() % 4;

                if(r3 == 0){
                    r = 0, r2 = 0;
                } else if (r3 == 1){
                    r = 0, r2 = 2;
                } else if (r3 == 2){
                    r = 2, r2 = 0;
                } else if (r3 == 3){
                    r = 2, r2 = 2;
                }
            } else if (square[1][1] == userMark){
                //If the user moves to the center AI moves to the opposite corner.
                if(square[0][0] == aiMark && checker(2,2)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 2;
                } else if (square[0][2] == aiMark && checker(2,0)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 0;
                } else if (square[2][0] == aiMark && checker(0,2)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 2;
                } else if (square[2][2] == aiMark && checker(0,0)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 0;
                }
            } else if (square[1][1] != userMark){
                //If the user does not move to the center AI moves to another corner which ensures a win.
                if(checker(0,0)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 0;
                } else if (checker(0,2)){
                    r = 0, r2 = 2;
                } else if (checker(2,0)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 0;
                } else if (checker(2,2)){
                    r = 2, r2 = 2;
                }
            }

            break;
    }

    //CODE FOR CHECKING IMMINENT USER VICTORY BEGINS HERE.

    //Checks diagonals.
    if(square[2][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[0][2] == ' '){
        r = 0, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[2][0] == ' ' && square[1][1] == userMark && square[0][2] == userMark){
        r = 2, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == ' ' && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][2] == userMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][2] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[2][2] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[2][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[0][2] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    }

    //Checks all vertical possibilities.
    if(square[0][0] == userMark && square[1][0] == userMark && square[2][0] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == userMark && square[1][0] == ' ' && square[2][0] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == ' ' && square[1][0] == userMark && square[2][0] == userMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][1] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][1] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][1] == userMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[2][1] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][1] == ' ' && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][1] == userMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][2] == userMark && square[1][2] == userMark && square[2][2] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][2] == userMark && square[1][2] == ' ' && square[2][2] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][2] == ' ' && square[1][2] == userMark && square[2][2] == userMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 2;
    }

    //Checks all horizontal possibilities.
    if(square[0][0] == userMark && square[0][1] == userMark && square[0][2] == ' '){
        r = 0, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][0] == userMark && square[0][1] == ' ' && square[0][2] == userMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][0] == ' ' && square[0][1] == userMark && square[0][2] == userMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[1][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[1][2] == ' '){
        r = 1, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[1][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[1][2] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[1][0] == ' ' && square[1][1] == userMark && square[1][2] == userMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[2][0] == userMark && square[2][1] == userMark && square[2][2] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[2][0] == userMark && square[2][1] == ' ' && square[2][2] == userMark){
        r = 2, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[2][0] == ' ' && square[2][1] == userMark && square[2][2] == userMark){
        r = 2, r2 = 0;
    }

    //CODE FOR CHECKING IMMINENT USER VICTORY ENDS HERE.
    //CODE FOR CHECKING IMMINENT COMPUTER VICTORY BEGINS HERE.

    //Checks diagonals.
    if(square[2][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[0][2] == ' '){
        r = 0, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[2][0] == ' ' && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[0][2] == aiMark){
        r = 2, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == ' ' && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][2] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[2][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[0][2] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    }

    //Checks all vertical possibilities.
    if(square[0][0] == aiMark && square[1][0] == aiMark && square[2][0] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == aiMark && square[1][0] == ' ' && square[2][0] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][0] == ' ' && square[1][0] == aiMark && square[2][0] == aiMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[0][1] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][1] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][1] == aiMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[2][1] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][1] == ' ' && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][1] == aiMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][2] == aiMark && square[1][2] == aiMark && square[2][2] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][2] == aiMark && square[1][2] == ' ' && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][2] == ' ' && square[1][2] == aiMark && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 2;
    }

    //Checks all horizontal possibilities.
    if(square[0][0] == aiMark && square[0][1] == aiMark && square[0][2] == ' '){
        r = 0, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[0][0] == aiMark && square[0][1] == ' ' && square[0][2] == aiMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[0][0] == ' ' && square[0][1] == aiMark && square[0][2] == aiMark){
        r = 0, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[1][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[1][2] == ' '){
        r = 1, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[1][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == ' ' && square[1][2] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[1][0] == ' ' && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[1][2] == aiMark){
        r = 1, r2 = 0;
    } else if (square[2][0] == aiMark && square[2][1] == aiMark && square[2][2] == ' '){
        r = 2, r2 = 2;
    } else if (square[2][0] == aiMark && square[2][1] == ' ' && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        r = 2, r2 = 1;
    } else if (square[2][0] == ' ' && square[2][1] == aiMark && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        r = 2, r2 = 0;
    }

    //CODE FOR CHECKING IMMINENT COMPUTER VICTORY ENDS HERE.

    square[r][r2] = aiMark;

    if(lose()){
        cout<<"You have lost!\n";
        return;
    }

    if(full()){
        cout<<"You have tied the computer!\n";
        return;
    }

    if(!full() && !lose()){
        cout<<"Computer move: "<<r<<" "<<r2<<endl;
    }
}

//Checks to see if the user has made three moves in a row.
bool Board::win()
{
    if(square[0][0] == userMark && square[0][1] == userMark && square[0][2] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[1][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[1][2] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[2][0] == userMark && square[2][1] == userMark && square[2][2] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][0] == userMark && square[1][0] == userMark && square[2][0] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][1] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][1] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][2] == userMark && square[1][2] == userMark && square[2][2] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][0] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][2] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][2] == userMark && square[1][1] == userMark && square[2][0] == userMark){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Checks to see if computer has made three moves in a row.
bool Board::lose()
{
    if(square[0][0] == aiMark && square[0][1] == aiMark && square[0][2] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[1][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[1][2] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[2][0] == aiMark && square[2][1] == aiMark && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][0] == aiMark && square[1][0] == aiMark && square[2][0] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][1] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][1] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][2] == aiMark && square[1][2] == aiMark && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][0] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][2] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else if (square[0][2] == aiMark && square[1][1] == aiMark && square[2][0] == aiMark){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Checks to see if all the squares are full; if they are, it returns false to indicate a tie.
bool Board::full()
{
    short count = 0;
    for(short i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(short j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            if(square[i][j] == aiMark || square[i][j] == userMark){
                count++;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    if(count == 9){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Clears board in event that it is not the first game.
void Board::clear()
{
    for(short i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(short j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            square[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Board bobj;
    short choice, num, num2, count = 0;
    char choice2;

    //Displays instructions for users (only first time).
    bobj.instructions();

    do {
        count++;

        cout<<endl<<"Game "<<count<<"\n";
        for(short i = 0; i < 26; i++){
            cout<<"-";
        }
        cout<<endl;

        cout<<"Select Player 1:\n"
            <<"1. User\n2. AI\nEnter choice (ex. 1 or 2): ";
        cin>>choice;

        //Determines which code to run based on who is Player 1
        //(i.e. runs case 1 if user is Player 1 and case 2 if AI is Player 1).
        switch(choice){
            //Runs when user is Player 1.
            case 1:
                cout<<"The game has begun. You are Player 1. ";
                do {
                    cout<<"Enter your move as a coordinance: ";
                    cin>>num>>num2;

                    while(num > 3 || num < 0 || num2 > 3 || num2 < 0 || !bobj.checker(num, num2)){
                        cout<<"ERROR: you have not entered a valid coordinance.\n";
                        cout<<"Enter your move as a coordinance: ";
                        cin>>num>>num2;
                    }

                    //Executes moves.
                    bobj.userMove(num, num2);
                    bobj.computerMove(1);
                    bobj.showBoard();

                } while(!bobj.lose() && !bobj.win() && !bobj.full());
                break;

            //Runs when AI is Player 1.
            case 2:
                cout<<"The game has begun. The computer is Player 1.\n";

                //First computer move.
                bobj.computerMove(2);
                bobj.showBoard();

                do {
                    cout<<"Enter your move as a coordinance: ";
                    cin>>num>>num2;

                    while(num>3 || num < 0 || num2 > 3 || num2 < 0 || !bobj.checker(num, num2)){
                        cout<<"ERROR: you have not entered a valid coordinance.\n";
                        cout<<"Enter your move as a coordinance: ";
                        cin>>num>>num2;
                    }

                    //Executes moves.
                    bobj.userMove(num, num2);
                    bobj.computerMove(2);
                    bobj.showBoard();

                } while (!bobj.lose() && !bobj.win() && !bobj.full());
                break;

            default:
                //If user does not enter 1 or 2 runs this code.
                cout<<"You have not entered a valid option.\n";
                break;
        }

        bobj.clear();

        cout<<"Would you like to try again? Enter y/n: ";
        cin>>choice2;

    } while (choice2 != 'n' && choice2 != 'N');

    cout<<"Thanks for playing!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> [..] it seems rather inefficient, as I literally have to type out every case of possible victory or defeat. [..] Everything is in one 500 line program.

*Woah.* Yes, that **is** inefficient, regarding developer time and developer annoyance. I'll attempt an answer now nonetheless. My answer consists of two parts: Part one is a (non-exhaustive) list of things that could be improved in your code. Part two is a implementation of the same idea by myself. In order to be able to show you absolutely fine code I'm posting [my own code as another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145085/20977). That way others can review and comment on it easily.

---

### Review

#### Better not `using namespace std;`

There's a lot of discussion in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1116364) post.

#### `char` is a character, nothing else.

```
char square[SIZE][SIZE], aiMark, userMark;
```

and later

```
userMark = 'x', aiMark = 'o';
// a for loop setting all elements of sqaure to ' '
```

So a "place" on your board can be either `' '`, `'x'` or `'o'`. And it can be the same as `str[0]` with `char const * str = "BOooO";`. At least according to the compiler, wo wouldn't stop you doing `place[0][0] = str[0]`, because they're of the same type `char`. Instead of trying to enforce such a separation by "being careful" you should better let the compiler and the type system do this:

```
enum class Mark {
  X, O, None
};
// ...
Mark square[SIZE][SIZE];
```

#### Member functions that don't modify data members...

... should be marked `const`:

```
// NO:
// void instructions();
// Yes (sort of):
void instructions() const;
```

But ...

#### Member functions that shouldn't even be members at all

Why is `void instructions();` even a member function? It doesn't use / modify / need any data members / other member functions of `Board` at all.
Better make it a free function (with a descriptive name), like:

```
void show_instruction_screen();
```

#### Names

`board.showBoard` ? Redundant! Better: `board.show()`. Even better: `stream << board`.

`checker` ... of what? Better: `is_valid_move`.

`bool Board::checker(short n, short n2)` ... `n` and `n2`? Completely cryptic. `x` and `y` could be seen as acceptable, but better is `row` and `column`. The same goes for many of your local variables: `r`, `r2`, `r3`, `num`, `num2`, ...

`computerMove` / `userMove`. Hm. I can *infer* what *could* happen inside these functions: The move of the computer/user is "processed". But this also shows another issue ...

#### Do only one thing per function

Every function should have a clear job, which should be mirrored in the functions name: `is_valid_move`? Checks if something *is* a valid move. `launch_nukes`? *launches* nukes. `ask_for_move`? *Asks* (the user) for a move.

Note that this does not mean that a function "contains" all code necessary to perform its objective: `launch_nukes` probably calls `prepare_silo` which possibly calls `open_doors`. `ask_for_move` could call a generic `ask` that returns a string to be parsed by `parse_move`.

So split your code further into (smaller) functions.

#### Use loops

Most of your code can be greatly simplified if you use a loop to check whether the places in your `square` satisfy some criteria. Example:

```
bool Board::win() const {
  unsigned rowCounts[] = {0, 0, 0};
  unsigned columnCounts[] = {0, 0, 0};
  for (unsigned column = 0; column < SIZE; ++column) {
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < SIZE; ++row) {
      if (square[row][column] == userMark) {
        rowCounts[row]++;
        columnCounts[column]++;
        if (rowCounts[row] == 3 || columnCounts[column] == 3) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    rowCounts[0] = rowCounts[1] = rowCounts[2] = 0;
  }
  // Plus code to check the two diagonals
  return false;
}
```

#### Reuse code

Look at your `Board::win` and `Board::lose`? What's the difference? One uses `userMark`, the other `aiMark`. Make it a single function `bool Board::is_winner(Mark mark)`.

#### Better not use the `operator,`

```
r = 2, r2 = 1;
```

Works, but is unusual at its best. Better make it two clearly separate statements:

```
r = 2; // Ignoring the bad names here
r2 = 1;
```

#### seed only once

```
double seed;
seed = time(0);
srand(seed);
```

This is called on every computer move. Not good. Your random values won't be that random (just print them to see what I mean).

#### Use the standard library

You can get rid of a lot of your code when you use code that's already provided for you in the standard library. Some examples:

- The loop in `Board::Board`: [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill). (which is also the same as in `Board::clear`, so the former should call the later which could use `std::fill`).
- Checking for win/loose/full: [`std::count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) or [`std::all_of`/`std::none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Comment: Thanks very much for your review! I really appreciate it. Though, I am slightly confused about your comment to not use the `operator,`. Is this considered bad programming practice?